# Vector of pointer points to NULL when using push_back()

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have the following struct in my code which assigns x and y randommly generated integer values:

```
struct A{
    int x,y;
    A () : x(random_gen_num),y(random_gen_num) {};   
};
```

I have a vector of objects and need a vector of pointers pointing to each object:

```
vector<A> a(5);
a.reserve(5);

vector<const A*> apoint(5);
apoint.reserve(5);
for(const A thisA : a){
    apoint.push_back(&thisA);
}
```

When I try printing them using:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    cout<< i <<"\t"<< a[i].x <<"\t" << &a[i]<<"\t" << apoint[i] <<endl;
}
```

I get all my apoint as NULL pointers as follows:

```
0       8       0x29b1bd0       0
1       8       0x29b1bd8       0
2       1       0x29b1be0       0
3       8       0x29b1be8       0
4       6       0x29b1bf0       0
```

The code seems logical to me and works when I say `apoint[i] = &a[i]` in the for loop, but in the real case this is not valid as the indices of `apoint` and `a` might not be same.To my knowledge, I couldn't find an answered question with a similar problem. Is there a better way to insert pointers into vectors?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve],

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you think you need a vector of pointers to objects in another vector?

Comment: yes, not clear why you need `apoint`. Simply use `&a[i]` when you want the address of an element in `a`, though I doubt that you even need that

Comment: Yes, a vector of pointer is needed because in the actual program I want to that to another function for evaluation. But, thanks. I did not think about the scope of the thisA.

Comment: `apoint` contains ten pointers – five null pointers followed by five dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<const A*> apoint(5);
```

Makes a `vector` and  preloads it with 5 `const A*`s that will be default initialized. That means `apoint`, before you `push_back` anything contains 5 null pointers. Since the size is already 5, the `apoint.reserve(5);` does effectively nothing. This also applies to `vector<A> a(5);`.

This means

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    cout<< i <<"\t"<< a[i].x <<"\t" << &a[i]<<"\t" << apoint[i] <<endl;
}
```

prints out those 5 null pointers before it will reach the five added with `push_back`. Change

```
vector<const A*> apoint(5);
```

to

```
vector<const A*> apoint;
```

to construct an empty `vector` or assign into those 5 pointers  with `apoint[index] = &thisA;` and remove the `The`apoint.reserve(5);`.

But...

```
for(const A thisA : a){
    apoint.push_back(&thisA);
}
```

Needs to be broken down a bit more to spot a second bug. `const A thisA : a` makes copies of the elements in `a` that only exist for a single iteration of the `for` loop. These pointers are too short-lived to be of any use to you. You want references to the values in `a`, not copies, so

```
for(const A thisA : a){
    apoint.push_back(&thisA);
}
```

needs to be

```
for(const A & thisA : a){
    apoint.push_back(&thisA);
}
```

A note about storing references to items in `vector`s: This is usually a bad idea. If ask a new question and explain your goal, we may be able to suggest better alternatives. If you really do need pointers to `vector` elements, be very careful that you do not violate the [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) .

Answer (score 1):

```
for(const A thisA : a){
    apoint.push_back(&thisA);
}
```

You push a pointer that is no longer valid on next loop. You need a reference (`A&`).

All that said of course, assuming you really need a vector of pointers (do you?)